# make a data file of google drive account using google drive api

Tags: java, xml, json, google-drive-api, data-files

I'am want to get all of my data in google drive into file (xml or json it's not so 
matter).
the regular way to do it is like this:

```
Drive service = new Drive(somedata);
String fileName = service.get(fileId).execute().getTitle();
```

to get the file id,  it's needed to do this:

```
Children.List request  = service.children().list(root);
ChildList children = request.execute();
String fileId = children.getItems().get(0).getId();
```

the problem is that the:

```
String fileName = service.get(fileId).execute().getTitle();
```

take very long time for each file.

and if I want to create a data file that contain all my data it's will take a lot of time.

I need the file name for the presentation of the file system of my google drive account.

anyone dealed with it and know waht to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `children.list(root)` do `files.list(q='root' in parents, fields=nextPageToken, items/title)`. That way you get all of your titles in a single (paginated) fetch.

NB. This is pseudo code. Look at the Java library for the exact syntax

Comment: I don't quite understand what you just say,
can you a little ,more specific?

Comment: no matter, I underStand what you have sayd. Thanks a lot!